# Word for splitting of 1 language into 2?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics

Is there a word for the process of a language splitting into two languages? For example, romance languages descend from Latin, is there a word for the splitting process that led to the languages? In biology, the formation of two species from one is called "speciation". I am looking for the word for language "speciation".

Comment: Divergence? Linguogenesis?

Comment: "Divergence" is what I've seen.

Comment: I would not be afraid of "branching".

Comment: Is "Break up" good?